# how to split json format string in order to Deserialize is into .net object?

Tags: c#

The subject sounds unclear, but the logic is very simple. I have a returned response data that is in json format. I want to Deserialize it into .net object which I defined already. I use JavaScriptSerializer class Deserialize method, it requires the parameter to be string. Now my response data is in json format, and has **more than one** roots.

My code is

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create  ("https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxxxx");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

The responseText value is

```
[
 {
 "webinarKey":5303085652037254656,
 "subject":"Test+Webinar+One",
 "description":"Test+Webinar+One+Description",
 "organizerKey":73563532324,
 "times":[{"startTime":"2011-04-26T17:00:00Z","endTime":"2011-04-26T18:00:00Z"}]
 },
 {
 "webinarKey":9068582024170238208,
 "name":"Test+Webinar+Two",
 "description":"Test Webinar Two Description",
 "organizerKey":73563532324,
 "times":[{"startTime":"2011-04-26T17:00:00Z","endTime":"2011-04-26T18:00:00Z"}]
 }
 ]
```

I use following code to deserialize responseText to a .net object that I defined.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Webinar w=ser.Deserialize<Webinar>(responseText);
```

Error comes out says responseText is an array, not string. 
Then how to split responseText? I don't think it is appropriate to use string.split() method here.

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize array not single object `Webinar[]`? `ser.Deserialize<Webinar[]>(responseText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response text is indeed a json array (containing 2 elements), as indicated by the `[` and `]` characters. Try the following:

```
Webinar[] w=ser.Deserialize<Webinar[]>(responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `List<Webinar> w=ser.Deserialize<List<Webinar>>(responseText);`?